# Can I change the name of the Desktop directory?

Tags: xdg, desktop-directories

Is it possible to change Desktop directory name? If it is how can I rename that directory?

I've tried `mv /home/username/Desktop /home/username/newName`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes indeed you can change this by closing nautilus and opening a terminal, then do the following:

```
mv -v /home/$USER/Desktop /home/$USER/<new-name>
```

But thats only the first step on the change you intend to do, now open `/home/$USER/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and edit the following line:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/desktop"
```

To reflect your changes, like in the following example:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/<new-name>"
```

Then save, exit, and reboot and enjoy your different named desktop directory.

Comment: Although a lot of code breaks, because instead of `$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR`, they just use a hardcoded `~/Desktop`.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju That seems unlikely, since the line `$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR`  can point to a different directory in any language. ("Bureaublad" in Dutch).

Comment: Just to be on the save side `ln -s <new-name> Desktop`.